# Where do you store code snippets you use very often?

Tags: java, spring, configuration, config, code-snippets

I'm learning Spring framework. I noticed, that in every project I need the same or nearly the same xml configuration files, beans definitions with properties etc. I thought I could store those sample xml/code snippets I use everytime somewhere.

Do you have any idea what's the best place to store it (I mean some webapp? notepad? etc)?

Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: Github in some personal library or just use Spring Boot ;).

Comment: Template them in eclipse, so I can use them later with a few keystroke combinations.

Comment: It sounds like your problem is not storing code snippets, but bootstrapping new projects. If that's the case, would you care to clarify your question?